# Copying Your Public Key Using ssh-copy-id

Tags: ssh, git-bash, ssh-keys, openssh, ssh-keygen

I am trying to configure a SSH Key-Based Authentication and after i created one, i want to copy the SSH Public Key to my server. When i give the following command on git bash : ssh-copy-id username@remote_host , i am asked for a password.

1. remote_host must be the floating_ip of the VM that i am trying to connect to ?
2. Which password should i type in ?

It would be really helpful if you could answer my questions.

Answer (score 1):

On the first SSH operation  (here an `ssh-copy-id`), you would need the password of the remote account, in order for the command to add your public kay to said remote user account `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Only then subsequent SSH commands would work without asking for password (only passphrase, if your private key is passphrase-protected, and if you have not added the private key to an ssh agent, for caching said passphrase).